# Uncaught syntax error : unexpected token function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn javascript by creating a few classic arcade games and while testing my game, I received an Uncaught Syntax Error : unexpected token function from Chrome console and can't figure out how to debug it.
Here is the code concerned by the error :

```
function drawEverything() {
    //Fills the screen
    colorRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 'black');

    if(showingLoseScreen) {
            canvasContext.font = '16px Arial';
            canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
            canvasContext.fillText("You lost!", 395, 200);
            canvasContext.fillText("Score :" + playerScore, 380, 300);
            canvasContext.fillText("Total Score :" + totalScore, 380, 350);
            canvasContext.fillText("click to reload game", 380, 400);
    }

    if(showingWinScreen) {
            canvasContext.font = '16px Arial';
            canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
            canvasContext.fillText("You won!", 395, 200);
            canvasContext.fillText("Total Score :" + totalScore, 380, 300);
            canvasContext.fillText("click to advance to next level", 380, 400);
    }   

    //Score
    canvasContext.font = '16px Arial';
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
    canvasContext.fillText("Score: "+playerScore, 8, 20);

    //Lives
    canvasContext.font = "16px Arial";
    canvasContext.fillStyle = "white";
    canvasContext.fillText("Lives: "+playerLives, canvas.width-65, 20);

    collisionDetection();
    drawBricks();

    //draws the paddle
    colorRect(paddleX, canvas.height - paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight, 'white');

    //draws the ball
    colorCircle(ballX, ballY, 10, 'white');
}
```

Here are the functions called within it :

```
function drawBricks() {
    for (c=0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
            colors = ['yellow', 'red', 'purple', 'maroon', 'green', 'gray', 'blue']
            color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
            for(r=0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
                    if(bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
                            var brickX = (c*(brickWidth+brickPadding))+brickOffsetLeft;
                            var brickY = (r*(brickHeight+brickPadding))+brickOffsetTop;
                            bricks[c][r].x = 0;
                            bricks[c][r].y = 0;
                            colorRect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight, color);
                    }
            }
    }
}


function colorCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, drawColor) {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
    canvasContext.beginPath();
    canvasContext.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    canvasContext.fill();
}

function colorRect(leftX, topY, width, height, drawColor) {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
    canvasContext.fillRect(leftX, topY, width, height);
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to read my code and providing an answer if you are able.

Louis

Comment: That parses without error, Chrome should tell you the line number where the problem is (on the far right)

Comment: It will be great if you can also provide what is in the console. There will be the line number and function name where the error occurred.

Comment: Yep, what you pasted here has no errors whatsoever

Comment: Chrome points out the error as being on the first line :

Comment: function drawEverything() {

Comment: The error is caused by something other than the code you have pasted, which we can't see.

Comment: "unexpected token function" means that the `function` keyword is not in a right place, maybe you have missing close bracket?

Comment: Can you provide your html as well? Chances are that you are including this script after another one that has probblems

Comment: Here is the link to the full code:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwcN-2m9BgY6T2s2c2haOGU2ODA

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] (emphasis on the **minimal**)

Comment: There was a "<" missing when closing the </canvas> but now i'm getting an unexpected end of input on the colorRect function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this block

```
//Local functions//
//function handleMouseClick(evt) {
    if(showingLoseScreen) {
        gameReset();
    } else if(showingWinScreen) {
        playerScore = 0;
        //level++
        showingWinScreen = false;
    } else if(showingFinalScreen) {
        gameReset();
//}
```

You have a missing close bracket there, in the last `else if`. So you should close that block, no matter if you want to uncomment the function or not.

```
//Local functions//
//function handleMouseClick(evt) {
    if(showingLoseScreen) {
        gameReset();
    } else if(showingWinScreen) {
        playerScore = 0;
        //level++
        showingWinScreen = false;
    } else if(showingFinalScreen) {
        gameReset();
    }
//}
```